# Nginx 404 Error to some subfolders

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

Noobie question here.

I've setted up Parse-Server in my Ubuntu droplet and i'm currently dealing with an issue here.
My ssl is from `letsencrypt`

In this file

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

I have the following

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
# through to Parse Server
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
        location /parse/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location /test/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/test/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location /dashboard/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/dashboard/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

So the followin links are working fine

- https://example.com/parse/
- https://example.com/dashboard/
- https://example.com/test/

but they are working cause of the default file has the code to work fine.
I can't do that for all the directories that parse has for example

- https://example.com/parse/serverInfo/

is getting a 404 error.

Is there any way to make all the pages available without having to configure them in the `default` file?

***Update***

So when I put this inside my default file

```
    location /parse/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

I get no 404 error. This is because of the `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/` that is different from the first file that I've posted here.

But how can i do that for ALL the requests no matter `/parse/` or `/something/` etc? I cannot right down here ALL the folders and possible links that i will create inside server. Because at this domain I will also setup a website which will have `/assets/` etc and it will need each single one.

Isn't there any code to include ALL the possible links that it will be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture parts of the [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) entry using regex group, e.g.

```
location /(.*) {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/$1;
        ...
}
```

Comment: So with this example it will get all the subfolders etc of the "/parse/" ?

Comment: Not exactly, I thought `/parse/` was one example out of many. The above will capture everything following the `/` (e.g. `parse/`) and will place it where the `$1` is specified, so the outcome is `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;`
For another suffix, e.g. `/something/`, it will result in `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/something;`

if you want just following the `/parse/` (I have noticed you got different port for `/dashboard/`), you do something like `location /parse/(.*)`

You can create complex and tighter regex's than the one I provided. The one above will capture everything.

Comment: Actually no, i want to allow everything. I will try out your example and will tell you the result!